# When the user Presses the refresh button on angular 1 router. I want him to stay on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Reload routes my page to parent. 
I used Local Storage but that causes issue with latest data.

So the user will be on plansponsor.summary page and when he presses refresh on the browser i want him to stay on the page with all the information.

Right now whats happening is when the user presses refresh button he goes to parent Plansponsor page

```
myapp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap','ui.router']);

var states = [



    {
      name: 'PLANSPONSOR',
      state: {
        url: "/ps",
        templateUrl: '../script/planSponsorHome.html',
        controller: function($state){
            $state.go('PLANSPONSOR.SPONSOR');

        }
      }
    },
    {
        name: 'PLANSPONSOR.SPONSOR',
        state: {
          url: "/sponsor",
          templateUrl: '../script/planSponsor.html',
          controller: "planCtrl",params:{source:null}
        }
      },
   { 
        name: 'PLANSPONSOR.SUMMARY',

      state: {
         url: "/summary",
         templateUrl: '../script/planSummary.html',
         controller: "summaryCtrl",params:{obj:null}
        }
     }
    ]


 });
```

Comment: this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: That doesn't satisfy my question?

Comment: your url can store parameters you can use to query your server when you refresh your app. you can restore to the state it was before the refresh. the tutorials go over this, try playing around with [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2SSO4Y?p=preview)